# The dynamic value of post json data is implemented in postman

Tags: postman

I want to implement the dynamic value of post json data in postman. How should the value be set in Pre-request Script?

```
{
    "mobile": "1***********",
    "role": 1,
    "pictureBookId": 50,
    "sign": {{sign}},
    "ts": {{ts}}
}
```

```
pm.globals.set("ts", ts)
pm.globals.set("sign", sign);
pm.variables.set("ts", ts);
pm.variables.set("sign", sign);
pm.environment.set("ts", ts);
pm.environment.set("sign", sign);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

In json string should be enclosed with double quotes so

{ "name":"{{value}}"}

If it's a number then you can use

```
{ "name":{{value}} }
```

In postman you can have json as

```
{ "name" : {{value}} }
```

And control the quotes inside value:

```
pm.enviroment.set("name",'"string"')

pm.environment.set("name",1)
```

**About variables**

```
#setting global variable
pm.globals.set("ts", ts)
pm.globals.set("sign", sign);

#setting local varaible whic is available only for that particular call or run
pm.variables.set("ts", ts);
pm.variables.set("sign", sign);

#setting environment variable
pm.environment.set("ts", ts);
pm.environment.set("sign", sign);
```

All are valid but make sure you are aware of the variable scope:

Important : **Here scope is from top to bottom , but precedence is from bottom to top**

[image]

so if you have a global variable defined , it will be available across all collaction , and environment will be available across only that collections that uses this environment and so on.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#variable-scopes

**But variable predence is from bottom to top:**

if you have a variable with same name defined in local and in global , then the value will be resolved from local. So if you have a= 1 and a =2 in local and global respectively then value of a will be 1.

**Dynamic variable built-in postman:**

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/

post have dynamic varaible that you can use with request , this values are available in all other sessions like body ,header etc other than scripts.

you can use this values as {{$varaiblename}} eg {{$guid}}

**Recommendation:**

i will stick on to use

pm.environment.set("name","value")

and refain from other varaible scopes as its hard to know whether there are local , global , collection variables defined as its not straight forward to see this values from UI.

you can see from where the value is being refered for a varaible by hovering over it

[image]

E- environment , g- global , c- collection

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I learned some debugging methods. I finally found that the reason I kept reporting errors was because the dynamic value in the json parameter was missing "".

Comment: Similar to the following   {
    "mobile": "18*********",
    "role": 1,
    "pictureBookId": 50,
    "sign": "{{sign}}",
    "ts": "{{ts}}"
}

Comment: yes i answered for the question before the edit you made :)

Comment: @mahonggeng added more details about your issue you don't have to enclose it in quotes in response body you can do it in pre request script

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, different types of data need to be transferred in different formats, it will not be automatically converted, you need to add double quotes yourself. I tried it in the Pre-request script as you said and it was successful.  pm.variables.set("ts", '"'+ts+'"');
pm.variables.set("sign", '"'+sign+'"');